# 4K gaming laptops with up-to-date hardware?

Tags: laptop, gaming, pc

I'm looking to update my current gaming and work laptop to something featuring the latest CPUs and GPUs. Unfortunately, 120 Hz FHD screens seem to be more popular than 4K this year.

Does anyone know of a good gaming laptop that has a six-core 8th-gen Intel CPU, a GTX 1080 (or *maaaaybe* 1070), and a 4K screen or thereabouts?

Preferred but not necessary:

- Lots of storage space.
- M.2 raid support to transfer current hard drives.
- 64+ GB RAM support.
- 15.6 inches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After extensive searching, I found a few options.

1. [Eurocom X4C](http://www.eurocom.com/ec/specs(431)EUROCOM_SkyX4C). This is what I eventually ended up buying. It has up to 64 GB of RAM, two M.2 slots, the desktop 8700k, and 1080 GPU, and a selection of several different screens, including on UHD version. It's also 15.6 inches, so pretty much exactly what I was looking for. The only issues I'd mention are that it's somewhat prone to backlight bleed, and, like most computers built on a Clevo chassis, has a little give in the keyboard.
2. [Hidevolution Evoc P750TM-1](http://www.hidevolution.com/evoc-clevo-p750tm1-g-custom-built-gaming-laptop.html). It seems to be built on the same chassis as the previous, and has similar specifications. One advantage is that it comes with up to 2800 MHz RAM, rather than the 2400 MHz standard on the Eurocom.

There are a few other options I found (e.g. from Acer) that had a 4k screen, but either had "only" 32 GB of RAM, came with only a 1070, or both. If these aren't obstacles, one of these laptops might be the better choice, since they're much more professionally put together.